# FF4J with Spring Boot in IBM WebSphere 8.5.11 server giving Error 500( SESN0008E) while accessing static resources(css,img)

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-8, http-status-code-500, ff4j

I am using **FF4J-Web** as a maven jar dependency  in my Spring Boot application. I am able to run the application in local environment  without any issues( embedded tomcat and IBM Liberty Servers). However I am facing some issues in rendering view components when I promote the changes to development environment server(IBM WebSphere 8.5.X)  which seems to be due to authorization issue.  Please find below responses I got while accessing static contents.

**Response Code 200**:   https://dummyserverlink.com/rootcontext/ff4j-web-console/static/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

**Response Code 500**:   https://dummyserverlink.com/rootcontext/ff4j-web-console/static/css/bootstrap.min.css

**Response Code 500:**    https://dummyserverlink.com/rootcontext/ff4j-web-console/static/png/ff4j.png

As you can see above, **.js** files are downloading without any issues. But **.css** and **.img** files are not authorized and  accessible in the browser(Error Code Status 500). But all resources are present under static folder only. **Please note that since I have added FF4J as a maven dependency all the static contents are present inside WEB-INF/lib folder**

So if I  try to access the **.css/.png** resource directly from browser, I am getting error ‘**Error 500: SESN0008E: A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session owned by loggedUserName**.’

Disabling the security configuration in Websphere is not an option we can go with as the same server is used for multiple applications. Also I am using third party login API for authentication at server level.

Is there any other way that you can share you expertise to bypass the authorization error for static resources(css,img) that are  inside the WEBINF folder?

Regards
Dinesh

Comment: This error means that you are accessing same resources (.css/.png) from sessions that are anonymous (not requiring log on) and authenticated. Try to enable 'Use available authentication data when an unprotected URI is accessed' setting, or disable session integration via 'Session > Security Integration' Check this page for details [Configuring Session Security Integration](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHRKX_8.0.0/security/ssi_cons.html)

Comment: Which version of `ff4j` are you running ? There is no difference in the code to server css and JS : https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j/blob/master/ff4j-web/src/main/java/org/ff4j/web/controller/StaticResourceController.java